How to edit the clickable popup in R-Map
I made a map using mapview. When you click on a point on the map, you get a popup with the details of that observation.
However, not all the 8 columns in the popup are relevant to the map's target audience. So I want to reduce the number of columns in the popup to 2.
I tried using the function popupTable() that should be in the mapview package. However, when I try to use it, I get the following error:
Error in popupTable(Gemeentes, zcol = pop, row.numbers = TRUE, feature.id = TRUE) :
could not find function "popupTable"
If I look in de Rdocumentation (https://rdocumentation.org/packages/mapview/versions/2.7.8/topics/popupTable) it says 'These functions are deprecated'
Does the function no longer exist? If so, is there an alternative?

This function is now in a package called leafpop
